# Google Maps API Usage in Commercial App with Both Fee and Login

Tags: google-maps, conflict

I read lots of Stackoverflow and other website content about the Google Maps API Usage Terms for Commericial Apps.

I have a question about a conflict in terms.

The clause 9.1.1-a says that:

> (a) Free Access (No Fees). Your Maps API Implementation must be
>   generally accessible to users without charge and must not require a
>   fee-based subscription or other fee-based restricted access.

And the clause 9.1.2-b says that:

> (b) Mobile Applications. The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free Access)
>   does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile
>   application that is sold for a fee through an online store and is
>   downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store.

What if my application is downloadable from the Android Market with a fee, but the Maps API implementation is accesiable with subscription by a charge.

Is the clause 9.1.2-b is still applicable? Are there any priority between these terms?
Can I use Maps API for free in an application that is downloadable from Android Market but the API implementation is accesiable with paid subscription?

Comment: Is your implementation solely a mobile application?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the clause 9.1.2-b covert your app (even if this fonctionnality is only accessible with subscription by a charge) but I not a lawyer.

You can ask your question on google forum : (the google staff can answer)
http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!forum/maps

Or you can also try to contact the google maps API sales :
http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/request.py?&contact_type=gme

Best regards,
Julien

Comment: Ok, I asked to the group. I will inform this post. Thanks

Comment: @Osman.Gerwas did you ask the group? What have you learned since you asked this question? thanks in advance!